# laravel directorio public no existe

Tags: laravel-5

Instalé ayer **Composer** y cree un nuevo proyecto con la consola mediante este comando:

`composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel lp`

En esta dirección: **C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\ad** Todo iba bien hasta que intenté probar la aplicación, que fui mediante el navegador a la carpeta del proyecto, pero no estaba la carpeta public. Si voy a la carpeta de mi ordenador sí que está, pero en localhost no. Soy nuevo en este lenguaje, así que no se cómo manejarme.

Gracias por adelantado.

Comment: Sino mal recuerdo Larabel tiene por defecto la carpeta www. Los proyectos se guardan ahí

Comment: Lo siento, pero no hay ninguna carpeta www

Answer (score 1, accepted):

para visualizar la aplicación intenta estos pasos:
1. abre el cmd (tecla windows + r)
2. pon el siguiente comando para llegar hasta la ruta de tu carpeta:

```
cd C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\ad
```

3. ejecuta el siguiente comando para que se ejecute un web server con tu app.

   php artisan serve
4. ingresa por tu navegador preferido a la ruta http://127.0.0.1:8000

Comment: Al ejecutar el comandos me salen varios warnings que dicen que no encuentra estas dos librerías dinámicas: C:\xampp\php\ext\php_pdo.dll y C:\xampp\php\ext\mcrypt.so. Y al entrar en esa dirección (pero en el puerto 8080 y no en el 8000) me aparece las página principal de Xampp.

Comment: Cual es tu ruta principal de xampp? Yo creo que es c:\xampp\htdocs ahi deberias tener haber corrido el comando composer create-project —prefer-dist laravel/laravel lp, intenta crearlo en esa ruta que es la que xampp tiene por defecto, y luegos ejecutas php artisan serve

Comment: Todo lo que sale en localhost lo tengo en esta dirección: C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\ad. Creo que el problema no es el directorio de Xampp, sino esos dos ficheros que no existen